# SQL Server Analysis Services: Can't choose tabular mode

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I already tried both, installing a new instance and adding a SQL Server Analysis Service Feature to an existing one. Both possibilities lead to one view:

[Choosing between multidimensional/data mining mode and tabular mode not possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bydpv.png)

I can't choose tabular mode, no matter what I do. Any suggestions?
I'm using SQL Server 2014 but I also tried on a SQL Server 2012 instance, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012 and 2014, Tabular mode Analysis Services is only available in Developer, Business Intelligence, and Enterprise editions. If you are using Standard Edition media I would expect that behavior.

In SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition (plus more recent SQL versions), it is possible to install a Tabular mode instance of Analysis Services but it is [limited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) to 16GB of RAM.